# How to access packaged assets from Android native code (NDK r5)

Tags: android, android-ndk

The release of Android NDK r5 (along with the SDK for Android 2.3) brings official access to packaged asset files from **native** code. (release notes [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html))

1. How do you make that work? What is the API to use?
2. Will it work on all previous versions of the Android OS, or only on devices running v2.3?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your source include the header:

```
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
```

and add the library in Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -landroid
```

Officially it works on Android version 2.3+

Comment: Thanks. Apparently there has been no modification to the asset-related headers since 1.5, so I assume it is quite safe to use them on older versions... Have you tried it?

Comment: No, but I tried the private APIs in Android's libutils from previous versions and it worked. However you'll need very through testing to ensure full backward compatibility.

Comment: can you give an example of how I might use libutils from froyo to use the asset_manager_jni.h methods?